# Spring Data JPA: keywords inside method names. #findBy{columnName}{value}

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Since a method name like

```
 findByActiveTrue()
```

is valid, would it be posible to replace

```
findByGender("female")
```

with

```
findByGenderFemale() or findByGenderEqualsFemale()?
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

The approach, that you described, can be applied only to booleans and IsNull, IsNotNull

Check out docs, Table 2.3. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. What you can do is run that call through a service that passes `female` to the repository method. Something like:

```
public Object getFemales(){
    return genderRepository.findByGender("female");
}
```